# My Vinca ( Madagascar Periwinkle ) leaves has black spot & curling

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis

I am from Mumbai India. My Vinca ( Madagascar Periwinkle ) leaves have black spot & curling, 15 days old plant brought from local Nursery . I planted it in balcony on the 6th floor. I used potting soil. I am very disappointed looking at this plant as it may die after few days. Pease help me to save this plant.[image: vinca]